# Make an array from MYSQL fetch result

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me to get this to work, sorry if code is not clean, i am just a beginner in PHP

```
<?php
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ps_product";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");    

    while($prices3 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {

    $total_price = $priceCalc;
?>  
    <?=$prices3["id_product"];?>=><? echo $total_price; ?>,
    <? }; ?>
```

**The above code gives me the following result (ID => Price):**

3=>55, 4=>28, 5=>35,

**How can I add the result into an ARRY?**

I want to get this done, in order to look like:

```
        $prices = array(
            3=>55,
            4=>28,
            5=>35,
            ...
        );
        foreach ($prices as $id => $price) {
            $query = "UPDATE ps_product_shop SET price='".$price."' WHERE 
            id_product='".$id."' ";
            mysql_query($query);
        }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: where are you calculating $priceCalc?

Comment: My oh my... Both question and answers look like contestants for the annual PHP obfuscated code challenge. I understand you are a beginner in PHP, but that does not prevent you from using meaningful names, and even maybe throw in a few comments, or does it?

Comment: Once your code is working correctly, you could make a visit to [codereview.se] and ask how to improve it.

Comment: `<? }; ?>` <--- next time you write this, you'll be flogged to death with the complete collection of the latest ECMA5 drafts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$res_arr = array();
while($prices3 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {
$res_arr[$prices3["id_product"]] = $priceCalc;
}
print_r($res_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_push` like this:

```
$result = array();
while($prices3 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {
    $total_price = $priceCalc;
    array_push($result, $total_price);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$prices = array();
while($prices3 = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {
    $total_price = $priceCalc;
    $prices[$i] = $total_price;
    $i++;
}
?>
```